# Convergence of unknown series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following problem and I don't actually know how to solve it.

Let $x_n$, n belongs to natural numbers set such that ∑ $x_n$, n≥1 is convergent. Prove that the series $\sum \sqrt{x_nx_{n+1}}$ is convergent.

Can someone please just give me a hint on how should I resolve this?

Comment: Use x_n between dollars to print $x_n$ and \ sqrt{  } to print $\sqrt{ something }$

Comment: I assume you want to add the assumption that $x_n>0$, else alternating examples work poorly.

Comment: Write x_{n+1} not x_(n+1)

Answer (score 3):

For $x_{n}\geq 0$,
\begin{align*}
\sum\sqrt{x_{n}x_{n+1}}\leq\left(\sum x_{n}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum x_{n+1}\right)^{1/2}<\infty
\end{align*}
by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Since $2ab \leq a^2+b^2$ you have 
$$\sqrt{x_nx_{n+1}}\leq \frac{1}{2} x_n+ \frac{1}{2}x_{n+1}$$
and $\sum_n x_n$ and $\sum_n x_{n+1}$ are convergent.